# Angular SSR: how to prevent re-rendering of generated HTML in the client side?

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I'm developing a web site with Angular 7 + Angular Universal for server side rendering.

Some Angular component has a tag:

```
<iframe src='...'>
```

The server sends rendered HTML to the client.
Browser gets the HTML and starts loading page in the iframe. 
But once Angular application bootstraped in browser, HTML again gets rendered on the client side, and as a result loading of the page in the iframe interrupted and starts loading again.

Is there some solution to prevent re-render ready HTML (or some component) again if it's already rendered on the server?

P.S. I'm, using StateTransfer to prevent AJAX requests in the client, so it's not an issue.

Comment: You'd probably need to add a conditional to the iframe to only render if the platform is the browser.

Comment: Thank you @Brandon. I'm trying to use ssr to achieve performance benefit, so I want to load iframe's page fast as possible, before the Angular app bootstraped in a browser. The condition ``isPlatformBrowser()`` will help to prevent rendering again, but it will be after app bootstraping